# Call a Javascript function from mobile HTML Body onorientationchange

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call a Javascript function when I change the orientation of my mobile web application in a web browser (specifically Safari). The onorientationchange I have on my body tag is not firing as the alert is not getting shown.  If I put the call on the onload of the body the alert get shown.  Any ideas on how to trigger a function when the orientation changes of a mobile web browser?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            function updateOrientation() {
                var displayStr = 'Orientation: ';
                alert("orientation=" + window.orientation);
                switch(window.orientation) {
                    case 0:
                        //do something
                        break;

                    case -90:
                        //do something
                        break;

                    case 90:
                        //do something
                        break;

                    case 180:
                        //do something
                        break;
                }
            }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onorientationchange="updateOrientation();">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why is there an xml tag on top of your page? `<!DOCTYPE html>` should be sufficient. :)

Comment: This is an xhtml page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in the iPhone Simulator

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onorientationchange = function(){
        alert(window.orientation);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<span>sample page</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using jQuery?

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function( event ) {
  alert('changed');
});
```